# How to display a div with a smooth transition with Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, transition

I have a read more option on my website to display some information.

Currently my button toggles like an on/off switch the display property of the divs.

I want the whole div to appear by smoothly expanding down the page on click of the button, I tried some combinations with transitions but I'm having no luck. I know transitions don't work with the display property, any ideas how to achieve this with preferably just CSS and the one simple function?

```js
function seeMore() {
  const text = document.querySelector('#website-info-idea')
  const text2 = document.querySelector('#website-info-technical ')

  if (text.style.display && text2.style.display === 'block') {
    text.style.display = 'none'
    text2.style.display = 'none'

  } else {
    text.style.display = 'block'
    text2.style.display = 'block'

  }
}
```

```css
#website-info-idea,
#website-info-technical {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="seeMore()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-custom">About this Website</a>

<div class="col" id="website-info-idea">Idea</div>
<div class="col" id="website-info-technical">Technical</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: thanks for the snippet however only the text transitions here and the height of the div just appears straight away, any ideas how would i get the whole div to expand smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the divs to expand smoothly, you have to set a final state height - not "auto" - and the transition must include the change of height.

Thus:

```js
function seeMore() {
  const text = document.getElementById('website-info-idea')
  const text2 = document.getElementById('website-info-technical')
  text.classList.toggle("show")
  text2.classList.toggle("show")
}
```

```css
.col {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.col.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 23px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="seeMore()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-custom">About this Website</a>

<div class="col" id="website-info-idea">Idea</div>
<div class="col" id="website-info-technical">Technical</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
function seeMore() {
  const text = document.getElementById('website-info-idea')
  const text2 = document.getElementById('website-info-technical')
  text.classList.toggle("show")
  text2.classList.toggle("show")
}
```

```css
.col {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="seeMore()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-custom">About this Website</a>

<div class="col" id="website-info-idea">Idea</div>
<div class="col" id="website-info-technical">Technical</div>
```